# How can I prevent React from unmounting/remounting a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `react-router` and `react-redux`. I have two routes like this:

```
<Route path='/edit'     component={ EditNew } />
<Route path='/edit/:id' component={ EditDraft } />
```

where `EditNew` and `EditDraft` are data-providing containers that wrap an `Editor` component using the `react-redux` `connect` function:

```
const EditNew = connect(state => ({}))(React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <Editor />;
    }
}));
```

and

```
const EditDraft = connect(state => ({ drafts: state.drafts }))(React.createClass({
    render() {
        const { params, drafts } = this.props;
        const draft = findDraft(params.id, drafts);
        return <Editor draft={ draft } />;
    }
}));
```

Now, `Editor` is rigged up in such a way that when you begin typing into a blank `Editor`, it triggers a `history.replaceState()` from `/edit` to `/edit/:id` with a ranomly generated ID. When this happens, I get the following sequence of events:

- `EditorNew` unmounts
- `Editor` unmounts
- `EditorDraft` renders and mounts
- `Editor` renders and mounts

When I coded these two containers, I thought that the `Editor` component contained in both of them would be reconciled without unmounting and remounting. This is problematic for me for several reasons besides the extra unnecessary work, chief among which are that the editor ends up losing focus and proper cursor range after the unmount and remount.

To no avail I have tried specifying `key` for the `Editor` component to hint to the reconciliation system that it's the same component, and I've tried `shouldComponentUpdate`, but that doesn't get called, which makes sense given what React is doing.

Apart from combining the two containers into one container with more complicated `render()` logic, is there anything I can do to prevent the `Editor` component from unmounting/remounting during the history transition?

Comment: It sounds like it's working the way it's supposed to; you are changing the top-level component, of which `Editor` is a child, so it should be completely destroyed and recreated under the new parent.

Comment: So I should merge the containers eh? I am looking at https://github.com/rackt/redux-router but I don't want to add more stuff to this project considering I want to migrate it to Relay soon.

Comment: Yeah, I would advise a single container, especially since you are talking about different states of the same thing, not using the `Editor` in a wholly different capacity.

Comment: Thanks, will do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[React’s Reconciliation Algorithm](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) says that if the element has a different type (in this case, `EditNew` and `EditDraft`), then React will “tear down the old tree and build the new tree from scratch.”

To prevent this, you need to use the same component for both routes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) and, if the route has changed from `/edit` to `/edit/:id` (you can check this getting the router info from the state connected to your component) return false, so it won't refresh the component.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that this isn't possible with `react-router` <= v3.

With `react-router` v4, this should be possible now: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4578