# How can I prevent the unmount in React Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a feature in my app where when the user tries to navigate away from an un-submitted form, they're given an confirm that asks them if they're sure they want to leave before saving their changes.

The **componentWillUnmount** method seems like perfect candidate for this because it will fire for all the various ways that a user may abandon the form (changes a parent component state that causes it to disappear, navigates to a different route, etc...). However... I have no way to prevent the unmount when the confirm returns false.

Any suggestions on how I can go about implementing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent React from unmounting/remounting a component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151563/how-can-i-prevent-react-from-unmounting-remounting-a-component)

Comment: I'm sure you can use [`window.beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) function

Comment: No, you can't! You only update components on the view! Only will we work if you update the browser route, not the params after #

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is best handled via react-router: setRouteLeaveHook.

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.unregisterLeaveHook = props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(props.route, this.routerWillLeave.bind(this));
}

routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
  return false;        
}
```

And when component is unmounted, unregister the leave hook:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unregisterLeaveHook();
}
```

Comment: I just have seen something like that, thank for your answer it works well for me

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? I want to prevent unmounting conditionally

Comment: What's the alternate for functional component?

Answer (score 12):

Using [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) you can easily prevent route change(which will prevent component unmount) by using `Prompt`.

```
import { Prompt } from 'react-router';

const BlockingComponent = ({ isBlocking }) => (
  <div>
    <Prompt
      when={isBlocking}
      message={location =>
        `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}`
      }
    />
    {/* Rest of the JSX of your component */}
  </div>
);
```

Here `isBlocking` should be a `bool` indicating whether a blocking prompt should be shown or not. You can find a complete [demo on react-router website](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions)

This method will work for `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter`, but if you are using `MemoryRouter`, you need to create your Router as shown below then use Prompt in your components:

```
<MemoryRouter
  getUserConfirmation={(message, callback) => {
    callback(window.confirm(message));
  }}
>
  {/* Your App */}
</MemoryRouter>
```

You need to manually pass the `getUserConfirmation` prop which is a function.
You can modify this function as you like in any Router(Browser, Memory or Hash) to create your custom confirmation dialog(eg. a modal) instead of using the browser's default `confirm`.

Comment: It performs a URL deffect - when the Prompt window is appearing - it changes URL string to previous one. Then you're clicking Cancel button and there comes a surprise - URL can be changed back or NOT. But you're staying on your current page, and that's okay.
This problem's coming from 2017 and seems like still not resolved

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing that in componentWillUnmount. I usually want to do that in the store (if you are using flux architecture). It is usually the store that needs to keep track of all the data. The componentWillUnmount function is were you would want to unmount the store listener.

Comment: **Demon**, actually I found out other way to implement what I want, and that's right it doesn't use **componentWillUnmount**. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem. :) aa

Comment: What solution did you go with?

Comment: @JoshuaNavarroRuíz: What solution?